# Using neuroph source codes in android app

Tags: java, android

i have tried to use neuroph source code in java to create an android neural network  but it crashed. 
source link, at the end of page:
http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/tutorials/MultiLayerPerceptron.html
libraries address:
http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/download.html

my Activity class:

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import org.neuroph.core.NeuralNetwork;
import org.neuroph.core.data.DataSet;
import org.neuroph.core.data.DataSetRow;
import org.neuroph.nnet.MultiLayerPerceptron;
import org.neuroph.util.TransferFunctionType;

public class TestNeuroph extends Activity {
    MyAdapter adapter;
    ListView listview;
    List<Row> Rows = new ArrayList<Row>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_neuroph);

        adapter = new MyAdapter(this);
        listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        Button btnProccess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonProccess);
        btnProccess.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 // create training set (logical XOR function)
                DataSet trainingSet = new DataSet(2, 1);
                trainingSet.addRow(new DataSetRow(new double[]{0, 0}, new double[]{0}));
                trainingSet.addRow(new DataSetRow(new double[]{0, 1}, new double[]{1}));
                trainingSet.addRow(new DataSetRow(new double[]{1, 0}, new double[]{1}));
                trainingSet.addRow(new DataSetRow(new double[]{1, 1}, new double[]{0}));
                // create multi layer perceptron
                MultiLayerPerceptron myMlPerceptron = new MultiLayerPerceptron(TransferFunctionType.TANH, 2, 3, 1);
                // learn the training set
                myMlPerceptron.learn(trainingSet);
                // test perceptron
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Testing trained neural network", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                testNeuralNetwork(myMlPerceptron, trainingSet);
                Log.d("Add_Food", "save trained neural network");
                // save trained neural network
                myMlPerceptron.save("myMlPerceptron.nnet");
                // load saved neural network
                NeuralNetwork loadedMlPerceptron = NeuralNetwork.createFromFile("myMlPerceptron.nnet");
                // test loaded neural network
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Testing loaded neural network", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                testNeuralNetwork(loadedMlPerceptron, trainingSet);

                adapter.setData(Rows);
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_test_neuroph, menu);
        return true;
    }

     public  void testNeuralNetwork(NeuralNetwork nnet, DataSet testSet) {

            for(DataSetRow dataRow : testSet.getRows()) {
                nnet.setInput(dataRow.getInput());
                nnet.calculate();
                double[ ] networkOutput = nnet.getOutput();
                Row r = new Row();
                r.setInput(Arrays.toString(dataRow.getInput()));
                r.setOutput(Arrays.toString(networkOutput));
                Rows.add(r);
            }
        }
}
```

i'm using adapter to show input and output in listview:

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyAdapter extends android.widget.BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater myInflater;
    private List<Row> list;
    ViewHolder holder;

    public void setData(List<Row> list) 
    {       this.list = list;   }

    public MyAdapter(Context context)
    {myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);}


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        try {   
            ViewHolder holder;        

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView             = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.rowneuroph, null);
                holder                  = new ViewHolder();

                holder.Input            = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_txt_Input);
                holder.Output           = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_txt_Output);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } 
            else 
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.Input.setText (list.get(position).GetInput());
            holder.Output.setText(list.get(position).GetOutput());
                    }

        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            //MainActivity.Alert(null, e.toString());
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView Input;
        TextView Output;
    }
}
```

my "Row" class:

```
package com.example.test;

public class Row {

    private String _Input;
    private String _Output;

    public void setInput(String id)
    {this._Input = id;}

    public String GetInput()
    {return this._Input;}

    public void setOutput(String id)
    {this._Output = id;}

    public String GetOutput()
    {return this._Output;}
}
```

my row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

my Activity xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TestNeuroph" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonProccess"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Proccess" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:text="Input:" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="OutPut:" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonProccess"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

when i run my app, and touch button, it crashed.
log file:

```
09-21 11:50:40.341: E/AndroidRuntime(972): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-21 11:50:40.341: E/AndroidRuntime(972): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.neuroph.core.data.DataSet
09-21 11:50:40.341: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at com.example.test.TestNeuroph$1.onClick(TestNeuroph.java:38)
09-21 11:50:40.341: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
09-21 11:50:40.341: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
09-21 11:50:40.341: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-21 11:50:40.341: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-21 11:50:40.341: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-21 11:50:40.341: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
09-21 11:50:40.341: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-21 11:50:40.341: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-21 11:50:40.341: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-21 11:50:40.341: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-21 11:50:40.341: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

can anyone help me?

best regards.

Comment: Have you [set the ClassPath parameter](https://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html)?

Comment: i added all libraries one by one to my android project

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` means that the runtime could not find the library. It probably means that you need to set the ClassPath. See the link I posted above.